# NullInjectorError while testing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, karma-jasmine

I have the following problem while running ng test in Angular 12:

> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[BaseURL ->
> BaseURL]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for BaseURL! error
> properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'BaseURL',
> 'BaseURL' ] }) NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[BaseURL -> BaseURL]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for BaseURL!
> at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11101:1)
> at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11268:1)
> at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11268:1)
> at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:25332:1)
> at Object.get (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:25046:1)
> at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:3342:1)
> at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:3454:1)
> at ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:14737:1)
> at NodeInjectorFactory.MenuComponent_Factory [as factory] (ng:///MenuComponent/ɵfac.js:5:7)
> at getNodeInjectable (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:3549:1)
>
> Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
> at 
> at UserContext. (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/menu/menu.component.spec.ts:46:23)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:1)

The code for the spec.ts is:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';

describe('MenuComponent', () => {
  let component: MenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MenuComponent>;

const mockDishService = {
  getDishes: () => {
     return {
        id: '000',
        name: 'nnnnn'
     }
  }
}

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [ MenuComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: DishService, useValue: mockDishService },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

The code of the component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';
import { flyInOut, expand } from '../animations/app.animation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss'],
  // tslint:disable-next-line:use-host-property-decorator
  host: {
    '[@flyInOut]': 'true',
    'style': 'display: block;'
    },
  animations: [
    flyInOut(),
    expand()
  ]
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  dishes!: Dish[];
  errMess: string;
  
  constructor(private dishService: DishService, 
    @Inject ('BaseURL') public baseURL) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dishService.getDishes().subscribe((dishes => this.dishes = dishes), errMess => this.errMess = <any>errMess);
  }

}
```

I'm using the baseURL to obtain the information for a db.json file while running json-server --watch db.json to simulate that I get the information from the server, so I have a shared .ts file named baseurl.ts with the following code:

```
export const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';
```

And in the app.module.ts I import the const

```
import { baseURL } from './shared/baseurl';
```

and I add it as a provider in the same app.module.ts file:

```
providers: [
    { provide: 'BaseURL', useValue: baseURL }
  ],
```

I will appreciate someone is help on this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1: NullInjectorError**

This error message shows as your `DishComponent` requires `BaseURL` to be injected [`@Inject ('BaseURL')`].

> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[BaseURL -> BaseURL]: NullInjectorError: No provider for BaseURL!

**Solution for Issue 1**

Ensure that you add `BaseURL` in `providers` section for unit testing.

```js
const baseUrl = "your Base URL";

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    ...
    providers: [
      { provide: DishService, useValue: mockDishService },
      { provide: 'BaseURL', useValue: baseUrl },
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
});
```

---

**Issue 2: Return wrong value for `mockDishService.getDishes()`**

From `MenuComponent`, it is expected that the `dishService.getDishes()` return the value of `Observable<Menu[]>` or `Observable<any[]>` type.

```js
dishes!: Dish[];

this.dishService.getDishes().subscribe((dishes => this.dishes = dishes), errMess => this.errMess = <any>errMess);
```

While the `mockDishService.getDishes()` returns the value of `any` or `Menu` type, which the data returned was unmatched.

```
const mockDishService = {
  getDishes: () => {
    return {
      id: '000',
      name: 'nnnnn',
    };
  },
};
```

Hence you will get this error message as below:

> TypeError: this.dishService.getDishes(...).subscribe is not a function

**Solution for Issue 2:**

Ensure that the `mockDishService.getDishes()` returns value of `Observable<Menu[]>` or `Observable<any[]>` type to match with real `dishService.getDishes()`.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

const mockDishService = {
  getDishes: () => {
    return of([
      {
        id: '000',
        name: 'nnnnn',
      },
    ]);
  },
};
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-354un1?file=src/app/menu/menu.component.spec.ts)

Comment: After I made the changes based on your answer, I got this error:
Error: Found the synthetic property @flyInOut. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.
So I added the import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; and in the beforeEach(async () => I import the BrowserAnimationsModule, and now the test is OK, thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Yes, make sure that all the dependencies required by the component are provided before the start of unit testing. You may accept the answer as it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I totally accept your answer, thank you very much !!!